# Kreait Firebase Storage createStorage() error

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-storage

I wanna create a feature to upload images to Firebase Storage using Kreait and I'm not using any sort of framework just raw PHP. I went through [Kreait documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-storage.html) and they provided the code on how to initialize it, so I did that

```
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
$this->storage = $factory->createStorage();
```

but it gave a red underline on `createStorage()` in my IDE saying *"Member has protected access"*.
What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `createStorage()` method has been protected in the early 4.x versions of the library and has been opened in later versions. Based on that, I assume that you're using an old 4.x version of the library.

Please check your `composer.json` for the entry `kreait/firebase-php` and make sure that the version constraint is not fixed to a specific version.

Unfortunately, you haven't shared a lot of information, but as an example, if your `composer.json` reads

```
"kreait/firebase-php": "4.11"
```

change it to

```
"kreait/firebase-php": "^4.11"
```

(note the leading caret `^`) This will allow the latest 4.x version to be installed, and the `createStorage()` method will be available.

The documentation you link to points to the latest *stable* release, which currently is 5.14.0 at the time of this writing. If you're on PHP 7.2 or newer, I strongly recommend using the latest 5.x version of the libary:

```
"kreait/firebase-php": "^5.14"
```

If you choose to stay with a 4.x release, the latest version is 4.44 and you can find the documentation at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/4.44.0/